# Generate SHAP dependence plots

Tags: r, shap

Is there a package that allows for estimation of shap values for multiple observations for models that are not XGBoost or decision tree based? I created a neural network using Caret and NNET. I want to develop a beeswarm plot and shap dependence plots to explore the relationship between certain variables in my model and the outcome. The only success I have had is using the DALEX package to estimate SHAP values, but DALEX only does this for single instances and cannot do a global analysis using SHAP values. Any insight or help would be appreciated!

I have tried using different shap packages (fastshap, shapr) but these require decision tree based models. I tried creating an XGBoost model in caret but this did not implement well with the shap packages in r and I could not get the outcome I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I invested a little bit of time to push R in this regard:

- **[shapviz](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=shapviz) plots** SHAP values from any source, including XGBoost, LightGBM, H2O, kernelshap, and fastshap
- **[kernelshap](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=kernelshap) calculates** Kernel SHAP values for *all* models with numeric output, even multivariate output. This will be your friend when it comes to models outside the TreeSHAP confort zone...

Put differently: kernelshap + shapviz = explain any model.

Here an example using "caret" for linear regression, but nnet works identically.

```r
library(caret)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

fit <- train(
  Sepal.Length ~ ., 
  data = iris, 
  method = "lm", 
  tuneGrid = data.frame(intercept = TRUE),
  trControl = trainControl(method = "none")
)

# Explain rows in `X` based on background data `bg_X` (50-200 rows, not the full training data!)
shap <- kernelshap(fit, X = iris[, -1], bg_X = iris)
sv <- shapviz(shap)

sv_importance(sv)
sv_importance(sv, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(sv, "Species", color_var = "auto")

# Single observations
sv_waterfall(sv, 1)
sv_force(sv, 1)
```

[image: SHAP importance barplot]
[image: SHAP summary beeswarm plot]
[image: SHAP dependence]
[image: SHAP waterfall]

Comment: Man you are awesome! I have been using fastshap to generate shap values but I will try kernal shap instead

Comment: "fastshap" is a good option as well! It scale very well with the number of rows to be explained.